# AngularJS module dependency injection sharing its dependencies with parent module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-module

I have an AngularJS module:

```
angular.module("app", ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute', 'ngGridPanel']).config(function($routeProvider) {
```

As you can see it has `ngGridPanel` included via dependency injection.

Here is the definition of `ngGridPanel`'s module/directive:

```
angular.module('ngGridPanel', ['ngAnimate']).directive('gridPanel', ['$animate', '$compile', '$window', '$document', '$timeout', function ($animate, $compile, $window, $document, $timeout) {
```

As you can see, it refers to `ngAnimate`.

The problem I am having is that once I inject `ngGridPanel` into my app, every element in my app is suddenly attempting to be animated.

Now, as [described in this Angular.js GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8224), `ngAnimate` will assume everything should be animated. Once I realized this is the expected behaviour, I realized that **I never included ngAnimate into my app module in the first place**.

So why would it be affecting my entire application? Shouldn't it only take effect in the directive that belongs to the `ngGridPanel` module?

So how is `ngAnimate` affecting the parent module scope? Is this normal?

---

**Side-note:** At this point I haven't even utilized the `ngGridPanel` directive at all. I have merely injected it into my app.

**Side-note 2:** Once I implemented a class name filter (`$animateProvider.classNameFilter(/enable-animate/);`) in my app, animations stopped on all my elements but remained working in the `ngGridPanel` directive *without having to add the `enable-animate` class anywhere*.

Comment: short answer is dependencies of module dependencies are available throughout the app as you are witnessing

Answer (score 1):

If you depend on ngGridPanel and ngGridPanel depends on ngAnimate, then you depend on ngAnimate as well.

It is the exact same to you as if you had defined your app with
`angular.module("app", ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute', 'ngGridPanel', 'ngAnimate'])`
.

As for your Side-note 2, it seems likely that they have configured it to use something like `.classNameFilter()` as well so that animations wouldn't break if the user of their library decided to configure it differently, such as you did. I don't know too much about ngAnimate so that's just a hunch.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it is normal behaviour then. In regards to the `.classNameFilter()`, I checked and the library does not use it. It is probably only affecting my app and not `ngGridPanel` because I am applying it in my app config, and that probably doesn't impact dependencies?

Comment: Interesting. I wouldn't think that would be possible since once you are using it it's hard for angular to know what's a third-party dependency vs. what's your own modules, but I definitely could be wrong.